# Data validation with pandas_schema

Tags: python, validation

I would like to read a CSV data file using Python pandas library and create visualizations.
First, I decided to validate the data.
I want to use the pandas_schema module to validate the data at each column.
The initial data file has 26 columns.
My code:

```
from pandas_schema import Column, Schema 
from pandas_schema.validation import LeadingWhitespaceValidation, TrailingWhitespaceValidation, CanConvertValidation, MatchesPatternValidation, InRangeValidation, InListValidation



schema = Schema ([
    Column('Symboling', [InRangeValidation(-3,3)] ) ,  #integer from -3 to 3 
    Column('Normalized Loss', [InRangeValidation(65,256)] )  , # integer from 65 to 256
    Column('Make',[LeadingWhitespaceValidation(), TrailingWhitespaceValidation()] )  , # text 
    Column('Fuel Type', [InListValidation(['diesel', 'gas'])]), # diesel, gas
    Column('Aspiration'), # text 
    Column('Num of Doors' , [InListValidation(['two', 'four'])]), # text (two, four)
    Column('Body Style' , [InListValidation(['hardtop', 'wagon','sedan','hatchback', 'convertible'])] ), # text: hardtop, wagon, sedan, hatchback, convertible 
    Column('Drive Wheels' , [InListValidation(['4wd', 'fwd' , 'rwd'])]), # text: 4wd, fwd, rwd 
    Column('Engine Location' , [InListValidation(['front', 'rear'])]), # text: front, rear
    Column('Wheel Base' , [InRangeValidation([86.6,120.9])] ) ,  # decimal from 86.6 to 120.9 
    Column('Length' , [InRangeValidation(65,256)] )  ,  # decimal from 141.1 to 208.1
    Column('Width' , [InRangeValidation(60.3,72.3)] ) ,  # decimal from 60.3 to 72.3 
    Column('Height' , [InRangeValidation(47.8,59.8)] ) ,   # decimal from 47.8 to 59.8
    Column('Curb Weight' , [InRangeValidation(1488,4066)] ) ,   # integer from 1488 to 4066
    Column('Engine Type'),[InListValidation(['ohc', 'dohcv', 'l', 'ohc', 'ohcf', 'ohcv', 'rotor'])] , # text 
    Column('Num of Cylinders' , [InListValidation(['two','four','three','five','six','eight','twelve'])]) , # text: eight, five, four, six, three, twelve, two 
    Column('Engine Size' , [InRangeValidation(61,326)]) ,  # integer from 61 to 326 
    Column('Fuel System' , [InListValidation(['1bbl', '2bbl', '4bbl', 'idi','mfi','mpfi','spdi','spfi'])]), #string: 1bbl, 2bbl, 4bbl, idi,mfi,mpfi,spdi,spfi 
    Column('Bore' , [InRangeValidation(2.54,3.94)] ) , # decimal from 2.54 to 3.94 
    Column('Stroke', [InRangeValidation(2.07,4.17)] ) , #decimal from 2.07 to 4.17 
    Column('Compression Ratio' , [InRangeValidation(7,23)] ), #  integer: from 7 to 23 
    Column('Horsepower' , [InRangeValidation(48,288)] ),  # integer:from 48 to 288 
    Column('Peak rmp'), [InRangeValidation(4150,6600)]  , # integer: from 4150 to 6600 
    Column('City mpg'), [InRangeValidation(13,49)]  , #integer: from 13 to 49 
    Column('Highway mpg'), [InRangeValidation(16,54)] ,  # integer: 16 to 54 
    Column('Price'), [InRangeValidation(5118,45400)]  # integer from 5118 to 45400 
])

test_file = pd.read_csv(('E:\_Python_Projects_Data\Data_Visualization\Autos_Data_Set\Autos_Import_1985.csv')) 
errors = schema.validate(test_file) 
for error in errors: 
    print(error)
```

After I ran the code, I have the notification:

```
The invalid number of columns. The schema specifies 31, but the data frame has 26
```

I don't actually understand how this happened: at the schema, I have 26 columns; and the data file has 26 columns.
Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: you have a few typos in your Schema definition, closing parentheses in Column definitions too early. This creates a list with 31 elements, which are interpreted as columns.

The correct definition should be:

```
schema = Schema([
    Column('Symboling', [InRangeValidation(-3,3)]),  #integer from -3 to 3 
    Column('Normalized Loss', [InRangeValidation(65,256)]), # integer from 65 to 256
    Column('Make', [LeadingWhitespaceValidation(), TrailingWhitespaceValidation()] ), # text 
    Column('Fuel Type', [InListValidation(['diesel', 'gas'])]), # diesel, gas
    Column('Aspiration'), # text 
    Column('Num of Doors', [InListValidation(['two', 'four'])]), # text (two, four)
    Column('Body Style', [InListValidation(['hardtop', 'wagon','sedan','hatchback', 'convertible'])]), # text: hardtop, wagon, sedan, hatchback, convertible 
    Column('Drive Wheels', [InListValidation(['4wd', 'fwd', 'rwd'])]), # text: 4wd, fwd, rwd 
    Column('Engine Location', [InListValidation(['front', 'rear'])]), # text: front, rear
    Column('Wheel Base', [InRangeValidation([86.6,120.9])]),  # decimal from 86.6 to 120.9 
    Column('Length', [InRangeValidation(65,256)]),  # decimal from 141.1 to 208.1
    Column('Width', [InRangeValidation(60.3,72.3)]),  # decimal from 60.3 to 72.3 
    Column('Height', [InRangeValidation(47.8,59.8)]),   # decimal from 47.8 to 59.8
    Column('Curb Weight', [InRangeValidation(1488,4066)]),   # integer from 1488 to 4066
    Column('Engine Type', [InListValidation(['ohc', 'dohcv', 'l', 'ohc', 'ohcf', 'ohcv', 'rotor'])]), # text 
    Column('Num of Cylinders', [InListValidation(['two','four','three','five','six','eight','twelve'])]), # text: eight, five, four, six, three, twelve, two 
    Column('Engine Size', [InRangeValidation(61,326)]),  # integer from 61 to 326 
    Column('Fuel System', [InListValidation(['1bbl', '2bbl', '4bbl', 'idi','mfi','mpfi','spdi','spfi'])]), #string: 1bbl, 2bbl, 4bbl, idi,mfi,mpfi,spdi,spfi 
    Column('Bore', [InRangeValidation(2.54,3.94)]), # decimal from 2.54 to 3.94 
    Column('Stroke', [InRangeValidation(2.07,4.17)]), #decimal from 2.07 to 4.17 
    Column('Compression Ratio', [InRangeValidation(7,23)]), #  integer: from 7 to 23 
    Column('Horsepower', [InRangeValidation(48,288)]),  # integer:from 48 to 288 
    Column('Peak rmp', [InRangeValidation(4150,6600)]), # integer: from 4150 to 6600 
    Column('City mpg', [InRangeValidation(13,49)]), #integer: from 13 to 49 
    Column('Highway mpg', [InRangeValidation(16,54)]),  # integer: 16 to 54 
    Column('Price', [InRangeValidation(5118,45400)]),  # integer from 5118 to 45400 
])
```

Answer (score -1):

Dataframe columns must match the number of columns in the defined validation schema. Alternate way is define a new dataframe with list of columns that you want to compare and use that for validation. (Not really sure if this is most efficient way, but it solves the purpose)

Comment: Hi, Kayvee. Please read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: my bad! I missed the last part of the question.